# Google maps stops kml/kmz support in February 2015

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, kml, openstreetmap, kmz

Google maps just told my they're deprecating their kml/kmz mapping service in Google Maps in February 2015.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/support/kmlmaps

I appreciate to be able to display my kml/kmz files in a [map](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=embed&hl=nl&geocode&q=http://radioactiefafval.nl/bijlagen/klei_en_zout/lagen.php), but I can't find a drop-in replacement. Any suggestions?

I don't really want to make Google-account...

Comment: Here is an [OpenLayers Example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/kml.html?q=kml)

Comment: and here is a [Leaflet Example](http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/kml.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options. For maps based on OpenStreetMap:

- [umap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr) allows you to create a map and import KML files.
- [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) allow you to host your own map. It is possible to display GPX files. For converting KML to GPX see [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Gmap4** which is an enhanced Google map viewer I developed.
Simply put your KML, KMZ, GPX or TPO file online.

Start with this Gmap4 link:
http://www.mappingsupport.com/p/gmap4.php?q=________________

Replace the underline with the http link to your file.
Paste the completed link into your browser.

The Gmap4 homepage has a FAQ, examples, quick start info (on the Help page) and more to quickly get you up to speed.

Gmap4 default map: http://www.mappingsupport.com/p/gmap4.php

Gmap4 homepage:  http://www.mappingsupport.com/p/gmap4.html

Joseph

Answer (score 0):

Try [GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/): you can upload your kml and let it draw the map.